# Linux command for extracting war file?

Tags: java, linux, war

How can I extract a `.war` file with Linux command prompt?

Answer (score 161):

Using **[unzip](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_unzip.htm)**

```
unzip -c whatever.war META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

It will print the output in terminal.

And for extracting all the files,

```
 unzip whatever.war
```

Using **[jar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jar.html)**

```
jar xvf test.war
```

Note! The `jar` command will extract war contents to current directory. *Not* to a subdirectory (like Tomcat does).

Comment: I actually think the `jar` command is better as it is designed to do just that.

Comment: @extraneon Could you explain why `jar` is better? They both extract the folder, so why in your opinion is `jar` better? I don't find *It was desinged for that* a valid argument.

Comment: @extraneon Well It depends on a particular situations: For example in terms of cpu utilization unzip is far better than jar (0.624 CPU vs 1.063 CPU utilized) cpu migration ( 0 vs 16)

Performance counter stats for 'jar xvf Calendar.war':
 325.095182  task-clock (msec)   # 1.063 CPUs utilized
16 cpu-migrations   #0.049 K/sec
3,049 page-faults   #0.009 M/sec
 0.305890466 seconds time elapsed
*
 Performance counter stats for 'unzip Calendar.war':
36.900667   task-clock (msec)  # 0.624 CPUs utilized
 0  cpu-migrations   #0.000 K/sec
419 page-faults   # 0.011 M/sec
0.059182220 seconds time elapsed

Comment: In unzip command, if we use '-c', it will extract files to stdout/screen (‘‘CRT’’). For extracting war file(all files) don't use flag c.

Comment: If you have a WAR file, jar already exists on your system. unzip might not.

Answer (score 33):

Or

> jar xvf myproject.war

Answer (score 9):

A war file is just a zip file with a specific directory structure. So you can use unzip or the jar tool for unzipping.

**But you probably don't want to do that.** If you add the war file into the webapps directory of Tomcat the Tomcat will take care of extracting/installing the war file.

Comment: Sometimes Tomcat won't extract the archive, and you have to do it manually. It can happen.

Comment: In that case you might want to restart tomcat, or use the 'touch <filename>' so Tomcat starts extracting.

Comment: Sometimes Weblogic doesn't want to use war :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `unzip` command.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting a specific folder (directory) within war file:

```
# unzip <war file> '<folder to extract/*>' -d <destination path> 
unzip app##123.war 'some-dir/*' -d extracted/
```

You get `./extracted/some-dir/` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Following command will help you.

```
unzip application.war -d output/
```