# How to grab a value from a war file without extracting it preferably, or extracting the minimum amount

Tags: ansible, yaml, war

I have a `.war` file called `app.war`, which contains a `test.properties` file which has a line called `appName: Blackberry`. The `test.properties` file could be anywhere in the WAR file, no specific directory.

What is the most efficient way for me to find the `test.properties` file, and then grab the value `Blackberry` from `appName: Blackberry` which is one of the lines in the file ?

The file looks like this

```
mainInfo: deployed 
app.Name: Blackberry 
testRun: success
```

I have heard about `jar xf app.war`, but not sure how to approach it. I am very new to Ansible, any help would be really appreciated :).

Comment: I'd suggest first trying to get this done manually (with `jar` command). Lookup the help for the command to know how to - list the contents; extract only the necessary file, etc. Ansible can come into picture once we have this clarity.

Comment: As I understood your question; The module `find` can be used to locate your file which could be located "anywhere", and with the help of `lookup`-plugin or `slurp` module filtered to `regex` you can your get desired content, which is `appName: blackberry` in this case.

Comment: I understand your question that you were looking for something like `unzip -qq -c app.war $(zipinfo -1 app.war | grep test.properties)` in Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question

> *How to grab a value from a `war` file without extracting it preferably, or extracting the minimum amount?*

I understand that you are looking for something like `unzip -qq -c app.war $(zipinfo -1 app.war | grep test.properties)` in Ansible and I've created a simple minimal example for.

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  vars:

    WAR_FILE: "app.war"
    PROPERTY_FILE: "test.properties"

  tasks:

  - name: Gather full path of '{{ PROPERTY_FILE }}', if there is any
    shell:
      cmd: zipinfo -1 {{ WAR_FILE }} | grep {{ PROPERTY_FILE }}
    register: result
    check_mode: false
    changed_when: false
    failed_when: result.rc != 0

  - name: Gather content of '{{ PROPERTY_FILE }}'
    shell:
      cmd:  unzip -qq -c {{ WAR_FILE }} {{ result.stdout }}
      warn: false
    register: properties
    check_mode: false
    changed_when: false
    failed_when: properties.rc != 0

  - name: Show content
    debug:
      msg: "{{ properties.stdout }}"
    check_mode: false
```

... *Consider using the [`unarchive`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html)
module rather than running 'unzip'*

Resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Show content] ****
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: |-
    mainInfo: deployed
    app.Name: Blackberry
    testRun: success
```

You have to adapt this to your environment and requirements.

**Thanks to**

- [View list of files in ZIP archive on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/216617/)
- [How can I run unzip silently in terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277728/)
- [How to unpackage and repackage a WAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269961/)
- [Linux command for extracting WAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833578/)

---

Please take note that the result `properties.stdout` is a list of strings which contains the key values pairs.

```yaml
  - name: Debug how to get value of key
    debug:
      var: item | type_debug
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ ansible_loop.index }}"
      extended: yes
    loop: "{{ properties.stdout_lines }}"
```

It is recommended to read them into Ansible variables. You will find plenty examples for how to do that here on SO via a search.

```yaml
  - name: Debug how to get value of key
    debug:
      var: item | from_yaml | type_debug
    loop: "{{ properties.stdout_lines }}"
```

**Thanks to**

- [Ansible - Check variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255461/)
- [Using filters to manipulate data - Formatting data: YAML and JSON](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json)